# How do I determine if a property is null using typescript?

Tags: typescript

first,i will httpRequest to url and get some data.

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "name": "john",
            "other": [{
                "a": 1,
                "b": 3
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to determine if this array(other) is null,so i will

```
if(data!=null && data.user!=null && data.user.other!=null && data.user.other.length>0)
```

I find it tedious and cumbersome to write a lot of useless code.
Is there an easy way?
in c# i will :

```
if(data?.user?.other?.Any()==true)
{
    //dosomething
}
```

How do I write it using typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on [typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) or higher, you can use optional chaining, very similar to what you're used to in c#. (Optional chaining will [eventually be in plain javascript as well](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)):

```
if (data?.user?.other?.length > 0) {
```

If any step along `data?.user?.other?.length` is null or undefined, then this code is shortcircuited and resolves to `undefined`. And then `undefined > 0` will result in `false`.

Comment: if version<3.7,how can i do?

Comment: Before 3.7 you'll use the tedious and combersome way you mentioned. Or perhaps use a utility library which simplifies it, such as ramda's [path function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path), though those functions usually can't enforce types.